# Do these conditions imply homotopy equivalence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have maps $f:Z\leftrightarrows X:g$ both of which are $\pi_*$ isomorphisms and satisfy $f\circ g \simeq \operatorname{id}_X$. Suppose also that $Z$ is a CW complex.

**Question:** Do the maps form a homotopy equivalence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they do.

The composition $f\circ g$ is homotopic to identity map of $X$ (because it *already* identity).

Note that $\pi_*(f)=\pi_*(g)^{-1}$, therefore $\pi_*(g\circ f)=\mathrm{Id}_{\pi_*(Z)}$. So $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $\mathrm{Id}_Z$ (using the fact that $Z$ is $CW$-complex).

Comment: But why is $g\circ f$ homotopic to the identity?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas because of  it is weak equivalence, and $Z$ is a $CW$-complex

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. That implies that $g\circ f$ is a homotopy equivalence but why is it homotopic to the identity?

Comment: @iwriteonbananas i edit my aswer, is it correct now?

Comment: How did you conclude that $g\circ f$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{id}_Z$?

Comment: Since $g\circ f$ is a homotopy equivalence, it has an inverse $h$. Thus, $h\circ g\circ f \simeq 1_Z$. So, $h\circ g \simeq h\circ g\circ f \circ g \simeq g$. Finally, we obtain $g\circ f \simeq h\circ  g \circ f \simeq 1_Z$.